# Save numpy array to CSV without scientific notation

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I was able to calculate the mean, min and max of A:

```
 import numpy as np

 A = ['33.33', '33.33', '33.33', '33.37']

 NA = np.asarray(A)
 NA = NA.astype(float)
 AVG = np.mean(NA, axis=0)
 MN = np.min(NA, axis=0)
 MX = np.max(NA, axis=0)

 print AVG, MN, MX
```

What is the easiest way to save those results to a csv documento using python? I dont have one so it needs to be created.

If I use this:

```
 np.savetxt('datasave.csv', (AVG,MN,MX), delimiter=',')
```

It will show as scientific notation in csv. How do I not get that but float?

Comment: Use the csv module, csv.writer in particular.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `fmr` parameter of `savetxt`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
In [153]: print(AVG, MN, MX)
33.34 33.33 33.37
```

The default write:

```
In [154]: np.savetxt('test.txt',(AVG, MN, MX), delimiter=',')
In [155]: cat test.txt
3.333999999999999631e+01
3.332999999999999829e+01
3.336999999999999744e+01
```

write with a custom `fmt`:

```
In [156]: np.savetxt('test.txt',(AVG, MN, MX), delimiter=',', fmt='%f')
In [157]: cat test.txt
33.340000
33.330000
33.370000
```

Or if you want values on one line, make it a 2d array (or equivalent with extra []), so it writes one row per line:

```
In [160]: np.savetxt('test.txt',[[AVG, MN, MX]], delimiter=',', fmt='%f')
In [161]: cat test.txt
33.340000,33.330000,33.370000
```

There are other parameters that you can experiment with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSV module

```
import csv
f = open('New file.csv',"wb")
writer = csv.writer(f)
for row in [AVG, MN, MX]:
    writer.writerow(row)

f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you but for some reason when using this method the file is created but nothing is in it. Any idea?

Answer (score -5):

A CSV or Comma Separated Value file is precisely just that a file that separates info with commas.

For example:
this info will end up like

```html
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Gender</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Luis</td>
<td>45</td>
<td>M</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Anna</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>F</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Brian</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>M</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```
Name,Age,Gender
Luis,45,M
Anna,30,F
Brian,28,M
```

Python has already a built-in module for this, the csv module, you can get some documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Is the HTML really necessary? The question was how to not get scientific notation

Comment: this answer doesn't add any value to the question. It only show how an HTML table it is converted into CSV but nobody ask for it.